# difference between algebraic set and affine algebraic set in hartshorne

Tags: algebraic-geometry

my question is basically already in the title. I just started to read the Algebraic Geometry book by Hartshorne where he defines an algebraic set but in some propositions a bit later talks about affine algebraic sets. So does he mean the same thing because i didn't see him define affine algebraic sets?

Thank you!

Comment: Is he saying *affine algebraic set* or *affine algebraic variety*. He defines the latter as irreducible algebraic sets.

Comment: Saw him in Proposition 1.7 using *affine algebraic set*. He is using it there as his definition of *algebraic set*.

Answer (score 0):

an algebraic set (or variety) is the zero set of a polynomial whose 
coefficients belong to a given
field k, considered as a subset of k^n.

if k contains R k^n may be considered affine space,
in the sense that it is closed under u,v-->au+(1-a)v for all a in R,
and then the algebraic set may be called affine.

some authors use variety only to mean na irreducible algebraic set.

Comment: usually, defined as a zero set of a FINITE SYSTEM of polynomials. but once you multiply them all, all you need is just one polynomial.